# Master/Detail Flow template on Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to use the Master/Detail Flow template on Android 2.3. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is **YES**.

Two changes are needed to make it run on Android 2.3.

First the generated class ItemListFragment contains a layout constant that has been introduced in API level 11: simple_list_item_activated_1. This specific layout highlights activated list items. Which is useful, if you have a multi-pane layout, because it shows the user which list item is selected and displayed in the details pane.

I ignore the highlighting for now and just try to get the code to run:

```
int layout = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    layout = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1;
}

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(
    getActivity(),
    layout,
    android.R.id.text1, 
    DummyContent.ITEMS));
```

The second problem is the ActionBar, which is not available on older devices without adding an additional library. Since this is the topic of my next post, I simply ignore the ActionBar on older devices for now. Change the line with getActionBar() to this in the ItemDetailActivity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Now you get a Lint warning. That the call requires API level 11 but that your manifest file states API level 9 as a minimum. Add an annotation to suppress the new API warnings for the onCreate() method:

`@SuppressLint("NewApi")`

Now change your AndroidManifest.xml file to support API level 9:

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="9"
android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

With these changes, you can now run the project on  Android 2.3.

Comment: You mention more information being the topic of your next post.  Has such a post been made?

Answer (score 0):

The app will crash on Android 2.3 because it lacks some API > 10 resources so:

1. Go to "XListFragment" and change the following line:

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.main_list_item, android.R.id.text1, DummyContent.ITEMS));

Change the layout to one of your own.

1. Got o "XDetailActivity" and comment this line "getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);"

In order to get the actionBar the Compatability library should be used for this.